# Max of a column (column 2) from several dfs

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate max value of a column from several dfs and than i need that max of these max's. Trying by a function iterating over a list of dfs. However, looks like I am not able to figure out how to supply just one column to the function. Here is what I have:

```
maxFun<-function(x){
        max(na.omit(x))
}

for (dfname in df_names){
MAX<-apply(dfname[,2], 2, maxFun)
}
```

Any pointers please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(x=10:6)
max(unlist(lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:2)), "[[", 1)))
# [1] 10
```